# Libgdx - Custom Created 3d Mesh causes java.nio.BufferOverflowException

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, libgdx

I am using libgdx to generate some 3d mesh in code. Right now I am attempting to generate a flat plane with many vertices in the middle just to test things out, however I am received a `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.nio.BufferOverflowException` when I called `mesh.setIndices(indices);` where the variable `indices` is a short array.

I am not having any trouble if I have less than 180-150 indices. I wasn't able to figure out the exact number from trail and error, however I am certain that the exception will be thrown if I have more than 180 indices.

Here is my code for creating the mesh:

Firstly how I generate my vertices (I don't think this is the problem, but Ill put them in anyways) *Note that my vertex attributes are `(VertexAttribute.Position(), VertexAttribute.Normal(), VertexAttribute.ColorUnpacked())`

```
private float[] generateVertices(int width, int height) {
    int index = 0;
    float vertices[] = new float[width*height*10];

    for(int i = 0; i < width; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            //vertex coordinates
            vertices[index] = i;
            vertices[index+1] = 0;
            vertices[index+2] = j;

            // normal
            vertices[index+3] = 0;
            vertices[index+4] = 1;
            vertices[index+5] = 0;

            // random colors!!!
            vertices[index+6] = MathUtils.random(0.3f, 0.99f);
            vertices[index+7] = MathUtils.random(0.3f, 0.99f);
            vertices[index+8] = MathUtils.random(0.3f, 0.99f);
            vertices[index+9] = 1;
            index+=10;
        }
    }
    return vertices;
}
```

Secondly here is how I generate my indices:

```
private short[] generateIndices(int width, int height) {
    int index = 0;
    short indices[] = new short[(width-1)*(height-1)*3 * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < width-1; i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height-1; j++) {
            indices[index]   = (short)((j*height) + i);
            indices[index+1] = (short)((j*height) + i+1);
            indices[index+2] = (short)(((j+1)*height) + i);

            indices[index+3] = (short)(((j+1)*height) + i);
            indices[index+4] = (short)((j*height) + i+1);
            indices[index+5] = (short)(((j+1)*height) + i + 1);
            index+= 6;
        }
    }
    return indices;
}
```

Thirdly this is how I set the vertices and indices (note that 6 and 7 are the width and height of the plane):

```
    mesh.setVertices(generateVertices(6, 7));
    mesh.setIndices(generateIndices(6, 7));
```

Finally, here is how I rendered my mesh through a custom shader.

```
    shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("u_projectionViewMatrix", camera.combined);
    shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix("uMVMatrix", mat4);
    // rendering with triangles
    mesh.render(shaderProgram, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
```

I don't know what is causing this exception, any help is appreciated. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's inside setIndices function? Just maybe, you might allocate the wrong buffer size.

Comment: @Greffin28 setIndices() is a  libgdx function as shown in the API https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Mesh.html#setIndices-short:A-  I trust that there isn't any problem with that because it works fine under 180 indices, and It worked reliably in the past.

Comment: The docs don't mention whether or not the `set` functions will reallocate the buffers if they are too small. Try using [this constructor](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Mesh.html#Mesh-boolean-int-int-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.VertexAttribute...-), and see if it works.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson AHA, YOU ARE A GENIUS. I indeed limited my max vertices and max indices to 160 when i created the mesh object with the constructor you mentioned

Comment: @Fish You might hit the `getMaxIndices()` or the max indices you can upload. There's a few conatructor that you can use, [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Mesh.java) is the class file. Edit: lol woops too late, typing on phone is a pain..